# Docker Networking

Tags: docker, centos7, ipv6

Disclosure: I'm new to docker.

I am having trouble connecting my docker containers to the network. I have the container started and in its bash I use `ping6` to another address on the network and I get destination unreachable. I have no network access so I can't `yum install wireshark` to see what's going on.

I have two subnets (`fc8c:979b:1f4e:6ec7::/64` [my lan] and `fd45:73cb:008d:16b7::/64` [for docker-containers]). If these were physical servers I would assign the docker-host as ip `fc8c:979b:1f4e:6ec7:6ae9:a0dc:840f:1a81` and `fd45:73cb:8d:16b7:694f:c5d1:818:4651` to be the gateway. Then I would assign static, randomly generated, IPs from `fd45:73cb:8d:16b7::/64` to the docker-containers and setup the appropriate routes.

The question then .. How do I get docker-host to act as my gateway? How do I get docker-host to send the router advertisement (or equivalent) to the docker-containers?

I see a `docker0` ethernet adapter, but I don't want to configure it with `ip` if I need to use `docker` commands.

Comment: Use valid IPv6 addresses. Those you have chosen are reserved and may not be appropriate for assignment on live systems.

Comment: I'm in a lab. That space `fc00::/7`, while not globally routable, is defined in rfc4193.  Granted something might be wrong with my random number generator since it picked those subnets ;]

Comment: I'm well aware of RFC 4193. That's how I know that address is not valid. See section 3.2 for more information.

Comment: Like I said, I'm looking into my random number generator. It picked the same subnet for my live maintenance network and so far it works great for them.

Comment: So you can ping `fc01::1` but not `fc00::1` form your container correct? Can you make an `ip addr` and an `ip route` from your container? Can you check if ip forwarding is enabled on to your host machine? And also the iptables ruleset?

Comment: Did you enabled ipv6 in the docker daemon? [1](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/) [2](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/ipv6/)

Comment: My container is centOS which doesn't seem to come with the `ip` command. While looking for forwarding I found where there's a [config change](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/) that needs to be done to enable ipv6, but when I add that line I can't start the service.

Comment: @almdandi I will study up on what you linked me and let you know tomorrow if it was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Almdandi for linking the [documentation which covers IPv6 from Docker](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/ipv6/).

I was able to get IPv6 working by changing two things, and here's a list of everything required.

1. Docker
2. Two IPv6 /64 subnets (let `[Subnet_0]` be what the docker-host's `eth0` is connected to, and let `[Subnet_1]` be a dedicated /64 for the containers.
3. Radvd (or another router advertisement solution)

Modifying the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file to include

```
{
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "[Subnet_1]::/64"
}
```

Where `[Subnet_1]` is a /64 subnet from your space that will be used only for containers, and is not the subnet that the docker-host is attached to. (I used globally routable space from our /48).

Then I added a router advertisement out of the docker-host's interface `eth0` using radvd with `[Subnet_1]` as a route.

Docker seems to

- Setup the router from `eth0` and `docker0`, with their applicable subnets on its own.
- Sends the prefix advertisement for `[Subnet_1]` to the containers on its own.